# Checking if row movement option is enabled in a view

Tags: view, attributes, db2, metadata, db2-luw

DB2 allows to enable or disable row movement in a `UNION ALL` view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST.TWO_TABLES_V 
AS
SELECT * 
  FROM TEST.TABLE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM TEST.TABLE_2
WITH ROW MOVEMENT;
```

The last line in the above example turns on row movement.

I need to divide views by this property, and I've tried to find the metadata attribute responsible for the property, in the following `SYSCAT` views:

- `VIEWS`
- `TABLES`
- `TABCONST`
- `CHECKS`

But no luck. Could anyone give directions to a catalog view and column(s) I should check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT VIEWSCHEMA, VIEWNAME
FROM SYSCAT.VIEWS
WHERE  LOCATE('ROW MOVEMENT',TEXT) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see, that's the only way to know if a view potentially enables row movement. Unfortunately, it means that after that I have to parse the underlying query text: it can include comments, ending-beginning combinations and other false positives I'd like to avoid.

If there is no other solution to the problem, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @suPPLer -- If this method was not good enough (i expected views that would add in comments to mess me up for example) then I would look at SYSIBM.SYSTABLES or check online documentation for this table.   This is IBM implementation specific so it is not going to be in SYSCAT.  You could make two views with and without ROW MOVEMENT and compare rows in this table.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice, @Hogan , I'd tried doing that before asking my question but couldn't find any difference between such views in `SYSIBM` tables. I think, now it's time to parse views matching 'ROW%MOVEMENT' pattern.